# is it possible to add a condition statement in .yml file ansible?

Tags: if-statement, amazon-ec2, ansible, tagging

I have created a role and a playbook , Now in my playbook , I am defining Ec2 tags such as :

```
instance_tags: "Name={{ name }},bld_env={{ bld_env }},server={{ app_name }}-{{ bld_env }}"
```

I also have to make a condition here for bld_env thats suppose if bld_env is "test", add more tags .
can you help me out with tagging in case of conditional statement ?

Eg:
My

**tagging.yml**

file :

```
- name: Launch EC2 host
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    bld_env: "{{ bld_env }}"
    count: 1
    instance_type: "{{ size }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    ansible_ssh_user: "ec2-user"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    pem_path: "~/.ssh"
    group_name: "ec2hosts"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ lookup('ini', 'vpc_subnet section=vpc file=./{{ bld_env }}.ini') }}"
    assign_public_ip: "{{ ip }}"
    keypair: "{{ key }}"
    access_key: "{{ access }}"
    secret_key: "{{ secret }}"
    instance_tags: "Name={{ name }},bld_env={{ bld_env }},server={{ app_name }}-{{ bld_env }}"
    security_group: "[{{ group }}]"

  roles:
   - ec2
```

Now as you can see the instance_tags here , I want to add a condition under this instance_tags as : when bld_env is "test" add another tag "Label=ec2start-stop"
So this Label has to be added only when bld_env is "test" since I am dealing with multiple env here ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Jinja2 conditions inside expressions, for example (see end of line):

```
instance_tags: "Name={{ name }},bld_env={{ bld_env }},server={{ app_name }}-{{ bld_env }}{{ '' if bld_env != 'test' else ',other_tag='+other_tag_value }}"
```

This will append empty line if `bld_env != 'test'` or `,other_tag=<other_tag_value>` otherwise.

Comment: Thankyou but I can add if condition in my playbook itself which is a .yml file?

Comment: Provide more context in your OP.

Comment: Do check the description now. I have updated with an example now.

Comment: No, you can't attach any kind of condition to variable definition, only make an expression conditional itself (as I showed).